# componentWillReceiveProps state is different from render state after redux state update

Tags: redux, redux-thunk

First of all, all the relevant code (click on the filename for the full source code of that file).

[`LoginView.js`](https://gist.github.com/gajus/6d4d079b7b82762401c6#file-loginview-js)

```js
LoginView = class extends React.Component {
    handleLogin = (email, password) => {
        this.props.authenticationActionCreator.login(email, password);
    };

    componentWillMount () {
        console.log('componentWillMount', 'this.props.isAuthenticated', this.props.isAuthenticated);
    }

    componentWillReceiveProps () {
        console.log('componentWillReceiveProps', 'this.props.isAuthenticated', this.props.isAuthenticated);
    }

    render () {
        let {
            errorMessage,
            isAuthenticating
        } = this.props;

        return <div>
            <p>this.props.isAuthenticated: {this.props.isAuthenticated ? 'true' : 'false'}</p>
            <button onClick={() => {
                this.handleLogin('gajus@applaudience.com', 'nosyte');
            }}>Login</button>
        </div>;
    }
};
```

[`authentication.js`](https://gist.github.com/gajus/6d4d079b7b82762401c6#file-authentication-js) (reducer)

```js
if (action.type === 'AUTHENTICATION.LOGIN_SUCCESS') {
    return initialState.merge({
        isAuthenticated: true,
        token: action.data.token,
        user: action.data.user
    });
}
```

[`authenticationActionCreator.js`](https://gist.github.com/gajus/6d4d079b7b82762401c6#file-authenticationactioncreator-js)

```js
authenticationActionCreator.loginSuccess = (token) => {
    let decodedToken;

    // @todo Handle failure to decode token.

    decodedToken = jwtDecode(token);

    localStorage.setItem('token', token);

    return {
        type: 'AUTHENTICATION.LOGIN_SUCCESS',
        data: {
            token,
            user: decodedToken.user
        }
    };
};
```

The flow is simple:

1. User opens the page.
2. User clicks the `<button />` that invokes `authenticationActionCreator.login`.

The `console.log` output is:

```js
componentWillMount this.props.isAuthenticated true
action AUTHENTICATION.LOGIN_REQUEST @ 16:52:50.880
componentWillReceiveProps this.props.isAuthenticated true
componentWillReceiveProps this.props.isAuthenticated false
action AUTHENTICATION.LOGIN_SUCCESS @ 16:52:51.975
```

The expected `console.log` output is:

```js
componentWillMount this.props.isAuthenticated true
action AUTHENTICATION.LOGIN_REQUEST @ 16:52:50.880
componentWillReceiveProps this.props.isAuthenticated false
action AUTHENTICATION.LOGIN_SUCCESS @ 16:52:51.975
componentWillReceiveProps this.props.isAuthenticated true
```

The problem is that `render` has the correct state (the state after `AUTHENTICATION.LOGIN_SUCCESS`) and `componentWillReceiveProps` has the old state (the state after `AUTHENTICATION.LOGIN_REQUEST`).

I am the last call to `componentWillReceiveProps` to have the same state object as the `render` method.

Is this:

- a bug
- I am doing something wrong
- my expectations are false

?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It took me writing all this debug trace/question to remember that [`componentWillReceiveProps`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#updating-componentwillreceiveprops) API is:

```js
componentWillReceiveProps: function(nextProps) {}
```

In other words, my `LoginView.js` example should have been:

```js
LoginView = class extends React.Component {
    handleLogin = (email, password) => {
        this.props.authenticationActionCreator.login(email, password);
    };

    componentWillReceiveProps (nextProps) {
        console.log('componentWillReceiveProps', 'nextProps.isAuthenticated', nextProps.isAuthenticated);
    }

    render () {
        let {
            errorMessage,
            isAuthenticating
        } = this.props;

        return <div>
            <p>this.props.isAuthenticated: {this.props.isAuthenticated ? 'true' : 'false'}</p>
            <button onClick={() => {
                this.handleLogin('gajus@applaudience.com', 'nosyte');
            }}>Login</button>
        </div>;
    }
};
```

Comment: Did you ever figure out why? Is it because `componentWillReceiveProps` is passed with updated props even before `props` are updated? Thank you for  leaving the answer btw. I too did not check the API first and was spending hours trying to figure out what was going on.